# Restarting a program using a do loop in C

Tags: c, loops

I have a simple question that I'm sure many you can answer with ease. I am trying to make it so that my program restarts after pressing the 'r' character on the keyboard otherwise the program will close using any other character.

I know that I need to you a do while loop however I am having trouble figuring out what statement I need to use. Here is my code (shortened down):

```
 int main()

  {

  do {

  //program contained here//

   scanf("%c", &r);

   } while (_getch == 'r');

   return(0);

   }
```

It's currently not working at the moment, and I appreciate any feedback/answers! P.s. I am new to coding haha.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's weird to do so, why not use a simple `if-break`.

```
while (1) {
    //program contained here//

    scanf("%c", &r);
    if (r != 'r') break;
}
```

Comment: Hmm it still doesn't work, it still exits the program if I press r.

Comment: I prefer `for(;;)` to `while(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

What is `r`, and what is `_getch`? You haven't declared either of those variables. Try this:

```
int main()
{
    char _getch;

    do {

        //program contained here//

        scanf("%c", &_getch);

   } while (_getch == 'r');

   return 0;

}
```